# How do I trace all method calls in Visual Studio 2010 up to a certain breakpoint?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, trace, breakpoints

I am currently working with an application **not written by me** but by one of my colleagues that resigned more than a year ago. He did not use any comments in his code, nor left any workflows, notes or anything to document the flow of an application.

I have access to use one of the classes he has created, and within the class is a method which I need to reuse in my current application. I spent more than an hour trying to find out where he has referenced this method call, but for the life of me, I cannot seem to find it. I have seen that this method in his application does run, and it works just fine.

Is there any way I can trace all method calls from the start of the application up till the breakpoint I have inserted in this method in Visual Studio 2010? I never had a need to do this up till now.

**Update**

This is an ASP.NET MVC2 application. I have looked through all the views and controllers, used the search function set to entire solution, with case sensitivity off. I'm pretty sure code does not just run spontaneously :).

Comment: What do you mean by `he has referenced this method call`. When he used it, or where he created its body? Certainly you won't be able to trace ALL the calls of ALL the methods, but i doubt this would be necessary.

Comment: definitely when he used it. I know where the method definition is, don't know where it is called from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the last edit, I guess that `Find all references` button would suit your needs.
Unfortunately, you can't set breakpoint on the function declaration; however, if you set a breakpoint in a function body, you can then use `Call Stack` to find out where it was called.

If you still can't find it with it, i suggest you double-check your standard search function.

Comment: Sneaky place to put it. He referenced it in another method, referenced by a view. Thanks a lot